# What is the difference between "ps -ef " and " ps -ef | more" command in linux

Tags: linux, command, ps

I'm new in learning linux commands, please help me out in finding the difference between  `ps -ef` and `ps -ef | more` command in linux

Comment: [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) is [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command))

Comment: Read about piping of commands in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ps -ef | more` you pipe `|` the output from `ps` to `more`, so you can scroll through the results of `ps`. Use `man ps` and `man more`to see the description for these commands.
See http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php for more information on pipes and streams.

Answer (score 0):

`more` is a file perusal filter for CRT viewing. `more` is a filter for paging through text one screenful at a time.